# C++ - "Expression must be modifiable lvalue"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, operators

The following code gives this error and I for the life of me can not understand why. Any help would me much appreciated.

```
jdn_t julian_to_jdn(year_t year, month_t month, day_t day)
{
    double a = (14 - month) / 12;
    year = year + 4800 - a;
    month = month + (12 * a) - 3;
    return day + (153 * month + 2) / 5 + 365 * year + year / 4 = 32083.5;
}
```

Error   8   error C2106: '=' : left operand must be l-value C:\Users\Italo\Documents\F14 CPA Fanshawe\C++\Project1Files\8. Calendar (D)\Calendar\julian.cpp 46  1   Calendar

Comment: It's like saying `1 + 2 = 3;`.

Comment: Nope, C++ isn't a calculator. You're missing the "variable" piece of the scenario

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign a value to an expression - which itself gives a value

```
return day + (153 * month + 2) / 5 + 365 * year + year / 4 = 32083.5;
```

remove " = 32083.5" part to give

```
return day + (153 * month + 2) / 5 + 365 * year + year / 4;
```

Comment: Oh wow, I feel like a moron. I meant to use the - operator but I guess i hit = instead...